# Sync SQLite database between two iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, database, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I'm currently finishing up a project for IOS in Swift in which I've used an SQLite database to store data with SQLite.swift.

At the time of coding I didn't know that SQLite files are stored locally on the device/simulator and I need a way to run the app and have the database synced between two devices, as soon as possible. I tried swapping over to Firebase since I heard that would be a solution but I'm not at all familiar with it and am worried it might be risky given all my functions are written for SQL tables. I also thought of keeping the SQL and adding on a firebase database to fetch the data from but I'm not sure how to execute that.

The solution doesn't have to be 100% reliable for all cases- I just need to simulate running the app on more than one device with synchronised data.

Does anyone have any suggestion for a way to do this? Or a way to store the data on a computer so that it can be accessed by both devices?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There are no elegant solution with pure `SQLite` database. Just few offers:

0. Moving to `CoreData` (You will get all what you want with sharing data between devices)
1. Uploading database file to `iCloud` from one device and download it from another device
2. Build up classic client-server communication

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I might be able to upload the database file to iCloud and be able to read and write data? Because right now it's stored locally on the simulator

Comment: @BenMiller SQLite database is just a file. You need to find the file at some directory and upload it. I think you need to use FileManager or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Let iOS do the synchronisation via iCloud, e.g. use Core Data with CloudKit:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit?changes=_1